# jQuery change method on input type="file"

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input, event-handling, onchange

I'm trying to embrace jQuery 100% with it's simple and elegant API but I've run into an inconsistency between the API and straight-up HTML that I can't quite figure out.

I have an AJAX file uploader script (which functions correctly) that I want to run each time the file input value changes.  Here's my working code:

```
<input type="file" size="45" name="imageFile" id="imageFile" onchange="uploadFile()">
```

When I convert the `onchange` event to a jQuery implementation:

```
$('#imageFile').change(function(){ uploadFile(); });
```

the result isn't the same.  With the `onchange` attribute the `uploadFile()` function is called anytime the value is changed as is expected.  But with the jQuery API `.change()` event handler, the event only fires the first time a value is change.  Any value change after that is ignored.  This seems wrong to me but surely this can't be an oversight by jQuery, right?

Has anyone else encountered the same issue and do you have a workaround or solution to the problem other than what I've described above?

Comment: I generally avoid IE like plague.  LOL  But seriously,  I develop in Firebox so that I can take advantage of Firebug and its awesomeness and then test in IE, Chrome and Safari.  Why do you ask?  The .live() method (answer below) solved this issue for me.

Comment: @gurun8 Why hasn't your uploadFile() any parameter? I want to call the an ASP.NET MVC method like this, but the javascript should send the file it wants to upload as parameter

Answer (score 99, accepted):

is the ajax uploader refreshing your input element?
if so you should consider using .live() method.

```
 $('#imageFile').live('change', function(){ uploadFile(); });
```

update:

from jQuery 1.7+ you should use now .on()

```
 $(parent_element_selector_here or document ).on('change','#imageFile' , function(){ uploadFile(); });
```

Comment: Binding change event in Jquery will not work in IE<9, instead use native onchange.

Answer (score 83):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). Refer: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('#imageFile').on("change", function(){ uploadFile(); });
```

Comment: Good catch on the deprecation of live(), but the form you show doesn't work. The form shown by @LuisMelgrati works. And indeed, the page you link to gives the second form as replacement of this function.

Comment: Thanks @PhiLho, just found out the link I was referring to was .live() not .on()

Answer (score 13):

I could not get IE8+ to work by adding a jQuery event handler to the file input type. I had to go old-school and add the the `onchange=""` attribute to the input tag:

```
<input type='file' onchange='getFilename(this)'/>

function getFileName(elm) {
   var fn = $(elm).val();
   ....
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
function getFileName(elm) {
   var fn = $(elm).val();
   var filename = fn.match(/[^\\/]*$/)[0]; // remove C:\fakename
   alert(filename);
}
```