# input type=file click is not triggering through jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;"><input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" /></div>

$('#photo').trigger('change');
$('#photo').change(function(e) {
  alert("change fun");
});
```

But alert is not displaying i mean change is not triggering at all.
My question is how to trigger change from jquery without actually browsing through file 
`$().trigger('change')` is proper right?

Comment: event in your case is `change` not `click`, so trigger `change` instead.

Comment: check it once  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721250/jquery-change-method-on-input-type-file

Comment: better your try the bind function for change http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: put your jquery code in $(document).ready(e){ //yourcode } function

Comment: @Jai , yeah i tried with change trigger. But not working . Change function is not triggering

Comment: @SSS i have posted an answer i hope thats what you want, but yet you have to put correct event to trigger, that is `change` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See you have to stack the event properly, what i mean is :

1. First you create your event which is `change` in your case
2. Then after it trigger the event which will work

follow like below:

```
$('#photo').change(function(e) { // change event created
  alert("change fun");
});

$('#photo').trigger('change'); // then trigger
```

Although you can bind multiple events with the use of `.on()` method:

```
$('#photo').on('change click', function(e) { // change event created
  alert("change fun");
});

$('#photo').trigger('change'); // Here you can trigger either "change" or "click"
```

#### Note:

> You were triggering the wrong event and also at wrong place. You need to apply an event first only then you can trigger that event.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // if you want file change event try this
    $('#photo').on('change', function(e){
         alert('change function');
    });
    // Or if you want click event try this
    $('#photo').on('click', function(e){
         alert('click function');
    });
 });
```

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CBLQr/)**

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sgnk8/)

***Use Trigger event inside the change function***

```
$('#photo').change(function(e) {
$(this).trigger('click');
  alert("change fun");
});
```

Comment: No that is not what i want. I want to trigger change function without actually browsing

Comment: actually browsing mean ?

Comment: My input type file is hidden