# How to get data value from element class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" data-cat="electronics" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="dfile" id="dfile" data-cat="Decoratives" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="kfile" id="kfile" data-cat="kitchen" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="hdfile" id="hdfile" data-cat="Home" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="ffile" id="ffile" style="width:100%" data-cat="Furnitures" class="alertme">
```

How can I get data-cat attribute value where class alertme is exist? and thanks for reading my question. I am weak in English so please apologize me if I made any grammatical or spelling mistakes.

Comment: when you get data click event or default run page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".alertme").each(function(){
 var val = $(this).data('cat');
    alert(val);
});
})
```

```html
<input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" data-cat="electronics" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="dfile" id="dfile" data-cat="Decoratives" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="kfile" id="kfile" data-cat="kitchen" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="hdfile" id="hdfile" data-cat="Home" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="ffile" id="ffile" style="width:100%" data-cat="Furnitures" class="alertme">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how can I run run this function on change?

Comment: you just have to use `$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    //Your code
});`

Answer (score 2):

here is code to achieve this:

```
$(".alertme").each(function(){
    // Here you can fill your array or whatever you want..
    $(this).attr("data-cat"); 
});
```

Comment: how can I run this function on change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721250/jquery-change-method-on-input-type-file  see this change function of input type file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the data attribute and a loop do push the value to the data array

```js
var data = [];
$(".alertme").change(function() {
  $(".alertme").each(function() {
    data.push($(this).attr("data-cat"));
  });
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="efile" id="efile" data-cat="electronics" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="dfile" id="dfile" data-cat="Decoratives" style="width:100%" class="alertme">
<input type="file" name="kfile" id="kfile" data-cat="kitchen" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="hdfile" id="hdfile" data-cat="Home" style="width:100%" class="">
<input type="file" name="ffile" id="ffile" style="width:100%" data-cat="Furnitures" class="alertme">
```

Comment: how can I run this function on change?

Comment: @ShahRushabh wrap your code in change event, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get all elements with that class:

```
var aAlertMe = window.document.getElementsByClassName("alertme");
```

Secondly, for each element in the array insert its data into another array:

```
var aDataValues = [];
for(var i = 0; i < aAlertMe.length; i++){
    aDataValues.push(aAlertMe[i].dataset.cat);
}
```

And you'll have all the values inside aDataValues.

Comment: how can I run this function on change?

Comment: @ShahRushabh Easy. `window.document.getElementById("yourIdElementToAddOnChangeEvent").onchange = function(){
/*here will go the code*/
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$("input[type='file']").each(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("alertme"))
        alert($(this).data("cat"));
});
```

Comment: how can I run this function on change?